# Broken insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

What's wrong with this insert statement? I've looked over it multiple times, and I can't see what's wrong.

```
INSERT INTO tasks
       (task_id, priority, limit, total_active, time_limit, start_time, params)
VALUES ("d", "9", "1", "0", "1549699912", "1549696366", "");
```

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| task_id      | varchar(2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| priority     | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| limit        | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| total_active | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_limit   | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time   | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| params       | tinytext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`limit, total_active, time_limit, start_time, params) VALUES ("1", "d", "9", "1",`' at line 1

Comment: Columns with data type int are having double quoted values . Why ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed I changed the query to use non-quoted values and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` is a keyword in sql you need to add double quotes round it.

```
INSERT INTO tasks(task_id, priority, "limit", total_active, time_limit, 
    start_time, params) VALUES ("d", "9", "1", "0", "1549699912", "1549696366", "");
```

edit: if this doesn't work, you can use backticks for escaping:

```
INSERT INTO tasks(task_id, priority, `limit`, total_active, time_limit, 
    start_time, params) VALUES ("d", "9", "1", "0", "1549699912", "1549696366", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Priority column is by default 0. You can skip it in the insert.
Try this.

```
 INSERT INTO tasks( task_id, limit, total_active, time_limit, start_time, params) VALUES 
( 'd',  1, 0, 1549699912, 1549696366, null);
```

Comment: varchar(2) is an integer value? Dont't think so.

Comment: Priority column is by default 0

Comment: Added the primary key and it made no difference.

Comment: Skipping priority column did not help you?

Comment: Don’t use quotes for non-strings.

Comment: Priority column is by default 0, you are providing 9. I will not work

Comment: @JimMacaulay I believe default is only if you don't assign a value?

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quote for number

```
INSERT INTO tasks(task_id, priority, `limit`, total_active, time_limit, start_time, params) 
VALUES ("d", 9, 1, 0, 1549699912, 1549696366, "");
```

be careful  because  the error message you have in your question not corresponding to the code you are  show  .. you have  in error message

```
 VALUES ("1", "d", "9",
```

but in code you have diffrent value

```
 VALUES ("d",  ...
```

and as suggested  by Matthias Burger wrap reserved  word  with backtics

```
INSERT INTO tasks(task_id, priority, `limit`, total_active, time_limit, start_time, params) 
VALUES ("d", 9, 1, 0, 1549699912, 1549696366, "");
```

Comment: I removed quotes and it made no difference.

Comment: the error message you have in your question not corresponding to the code you are  show  .. you have  in error message  VALUES ("1", "d", "9", but in code you have ("d", 9, 1, ... so check better if you are using really the code i have posted in my answer  ...

Comment: it's the exact same error with different parameters dude

Comment: check better the code  .. you are really using and eventually update your question and add  also the others (significant) part of code

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit, total_active, time_limit, start_time, params) 
VALUES ("d", 9, 1, 0, 1549' at line 1